# Автопрокрутка вниз ScrollBar привязанной к TextArea

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Имеется textArea с прикрученым к ней scrollBar, реализованый в qml таким образом.

```
Flickable {
        id: flickable
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        TextArea.flickable: TextArea {
            id: output_field
            text: mainwindow.text
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
}
```

"mainwindow.text" возвращает значение переменной в которой хранится текстовое сообщение.

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ getText NOTIFY textChanged)

QString _outputText;

QString getText()
{
    return _outputText;
}

//далее по какому-либо сигналу

_outputText += newMessage;
emit textChanged();
```

После каждого вызова textChanged() отображаются самые верхние (ранние) сообщения.

Как реализовать привязку положения скроллбара к концу текста при его изменении, Т.е. как в командной строке - отображаются самые последние сообщения, но при желании можно прокрутить выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения положения ScrollBar{} в конце текста TextArea{} необходмо добавить обработчик события

```
onTextChanged: { textArea.cursorPosition = textArea.length }
```

тем самым выставив положеине курсора в конце текста.

Рабочий пример с имитацией добавления нового сообщения по кнопке ниже:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    width: 350
    height: 300

    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 5

        spacing: 5

        Rectangle {
            x: (parent.width - width) / 2
            y: (parent.height - height) / 2

            width: 2 * parent.width / 3
            height: parent.height / 2

            color: "silver"

            border.width: 1
            border.color: "black"

            Flickable {
                anchors.fill: parent

                clip: true

                flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

                ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
                ScrollBar.horizontal: null

                TextArea.flickable: TextArea {
                    id: textArea

                    wrapMode: TextArea.WordWrap

                    onTextChanged: { textArea.cursorPosition = textArea.length }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom | Qt.AlignHCenter

            text: "CLICK"

            onClicked: { textArea.text += "New message... " }
        }
    }
}
```